# Cannot run opencv-python script in node.js : No module named cv2

Tags: python, node.js, opencv

Using this code to for capturing image and it is running well on spyder-anaconda but I want to integrate with my app which is made on node.js platform but unable to do so.

the beginning of python code is as follows :

```
//cam_open.py
import cv2
import numpy as np

aarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

detector=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#------Id=raw_input('enter your id')----
Id=1
path= 'Dataset1'
sampleNum=0
while(True):
    ret, img = cam.read();
```

.
.
.

and code for integrating with node.js is as follows:

(note: I have used this code to run other python scripts and it is running perfect on them but when I include opencv it is giving me errors even though I have added opencv path to my environment variables too)

```
//index.js
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var pyshell = new PythonShell('cam_open.py');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {

    console.log(message);
});
```

the error I'm getting is as follows:

```
HIBA@hiba-pc MINGW64 ~/documents/sabah/driver-comp/test
$ node index.js
events.js:137
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ImportError: No module named cv2
    at PythonShell.parseError (C:\Users\HIBA\documents\sabah\driver-comp\node_modules\p
ython-shell\index.js:184:17)
    at terminateIfNeeded (C:\Users\HIBA\documents\sabah\driver-comp\node_modules\python
-shell\index.js:98:28)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HIBA\documents\sabah\driver-comp\node_modules
\python-shell\index.js:89:9)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
    ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "cam_open.py", line 1, in <module>
      import cv2
```

Can anybody here help me get out of this :)

Comment: You have to install opencv for python. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python